# Return first 'unsorted' join in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table 'ACCOUNTS', with fields ACCTNO and ACPARENT. One account can be the parent of another. One account can have many children.

It's been discovered that certain external processes are using the 'first child' in certain reports and outputs - but there's no actual 'reason' for any particular child to be 'first', just an unintended bug in the code.

First step in untangling this - I need a query, that can be re-run (but not often, so optimisation is not really a factor) that will identify, for all accounts that are parents, what their 'first child' is.

Problem - the 'first child' isn't necessarily anything to do with record ID. If I run the following query, for example:

```
SELECT ACCTNO FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE ACPARENT = '80005217';
```

I get a result of:

```
ACCTNO
______    
80007325
80007310
80007315
80007298
```

I can absolutely, 100% confirm that for this particular example, account 80007325 is the account ID being used as the 'first child'.

On the flipside, if I run a naive query of:

```
SELECT A1.ACCTNO, A2.ACCTNO AS CHILDACCOUNT FROM ACCOUNTS A1
INNER JOIN ACCOUNTS A2 ON A1.ACCTNO = A2.ACPARENT
WHERE A1.ACCTNO IN
(SELECT ACPARENT FROM ACCOUNTS);
```

then if I scroll down to where 80005217 is the parent account, I see the following list:

```
CHILDACCOUNT
______    
80007298    
80007310
80007315
80007325
```

It's sorted, even though it's exactly not what I want.

Is there a query that will get me a list of what I want in a single query? A list of all parent accounts, and their 'first child' as returned by SQL unsorted?

Comment: Rewrite your question. Provide script (relevant columns only) and consistent sample of data (you scroll down and saw `80005217 ` well.. it's still invisible to us) and desired output so we can easily recreate it and test our ideas.

Comment: How data got inserted on those tables? Have you tried reproducing this by creating test table & test data?

Comment: Predicting the results of an unsorted query is technically impossible. Even if you do manage to receive the same results every time you run the query - there is no guarantee the same row would be the first to be selected next time the query tries to access the table (Since the blocks might be read in a different order then). If there is a need to be able to predict the order in which your rows return, order the query. Simple as that.

Comment: The same order is output by the query every time if I input 'SELECT ACCTNO FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE ACPARENT = '80005217';' (or any other particular account). The ordering is consistent - just not based on anything.   

The end goal is to rearrange children and parents so that they ARE sorted when used - but first we want a record of what 'firsts' WERE being used.

Answer (score 0):

To guarantee records coming in a fixed order we must provide the database with sort criteria in the `ORDER BY` clause. If there is no attribute which defines "first-ness" then no guarantee is possible. Without an `ORDER BY` clause the records are essentially in an uncontrolled order, although because of 
database internals they often fall into some kind of pattern.

So, what makes account 80007325 the first child `WHERE ACPARENT = '80005217'`? Clearly not numerical order. Is there some other criterion? Date created? A flag column? Seems like you need to talk to your users. Do they really care which records come first? All the time or just in some specific report?

If your users cannot specify the criteria there's not much you can do...

...although I might be tempted to sort CHILDACCOUNT numerically by ACCTNO whenever it is displayed. At least that would provide consistency, and the users will get used to it.